# Dropwizard prometheus do not evaluate URI template

Tags: java, jersey, prometheus, dropwizard, metrics

I have a Dropwizard application that exposes metrics to prometheus using the dependencies below. However, if I create an endpoint GET /v1/book/{Id} the metrics exposed in prometheus contains the evaluated request parameters. How can I expose the metric with the template instead?

For example, if I do two requests, one for /v1/book/a and one for /v1/book/b, two metrics will be exposed in prometheus (counter, timer and buckets) instead of one for /v1/book/{ID}. How can I achieve this behavior?

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_dropwizard</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version></dependency>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I think, you could probably collect this metric manually within your handler method, or is this not possible?

Comment: I guess I could. But it would be nice to use the built in dropwizard metrics.

Comment: @AlexanderNajafi can you let me know how do we expose the prometheus end-point to scrape them in text format.

Comment: @VManoj check this guide out https://www.robustperception.io/exposing-dropwizard-metrics-to-prometheus

Comment: @AlexanderNajafi I export some of my custom metrics as well so will it be fine if I just add the dropWizardMetricsRegistry to it right ?